# Writing conditional statement with CON?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, con

How can I write the following conditional statement with CON?

I want to run all the conditions(simultaneously).

```
IF rasterA>0 & rasterB>0 Then (rasterA+rasterB)-(rasterA*rasterB)

                               &

IF rasterA<0 & rasterB<0 then (rasterA+rasterB)+(rasterA*rasterB)

                               &

IF rasterA & rasterB Opposite sign then (rasterA+rasterA)/(1-min(rasterA & rasterB)
```